# jq converting some json keys into csv

Tags: json, nested, export-to-csv, jq, data-extraction

I have json text that looks like the following

```
 {
  "requires_mfa_code": false,
  "key_vault": false,
  "id": 100442,
  "slug": "spredfns",
  "name": "Spredfns",
  "**provider**": {
    "icons": {
      "first_letter": "s",
      "color_code": "65c6bb",
      "large": "https://assetsedfast_lg.png",
      "small": "https://assets.dfast_sm.png"
    },
    "**capabilities**": {
      "has_ou": false,
      "has_import": false,
      "has_password_reset": false,
      "has_provision": false,
      "has_saml": false,
      "has_sync": false,
      "unsupported_browsers": [],
      "services": "authenticatab
```

I am having trouble parsing the category text headers like capabilities and provider.I can only get requires_mfa_code and id and name.My code is below:

```
 curl  https://www.example.com/api/v2/organizations/78762/installations?page=1 > test.txt; cat test.txt | jq '.[] | "\(.id) \(.name)" '
```

Can anyone please assist? I would like to get **provider/color_code**

Goal is below

```
id     slug     provider color_code
100442 spredfns    65c6bb
```

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question mentions CSV so I'll first illustrate how to produce valid CSV with @csv.

With your input (corrected to make it valid JSON), the invocation:

```
jq -r '[.id, .slug, ."**provider**"."icons"."color_code" ] | @csv'
```

produces:

```
100442,"spredfns","65c6bb"
```

#### Avoiding the quotation marks

If you don't want the enclosing quotation marks in the output, then you could use string interpolation, as in the original post.  If your jq supports `@tsv`, then an alternative would be to use it instead of @csv; the output would then be:

```
100442  spredfns    65c6bb
```

#### Including headers

Headers can be included like so:

```
(["id", "slug", "provider color_code"],
 [.id, .slug, ."**provider**"."icons"."color_code" ])
| @tsv
```

In this case the output would be:

```
id  slug    provider color_code
100442  spredfns    65c6bb
```

#### Older versions of jq

If you are using a version of jq that does not support the `."foo"` syntax, use the primary `.["foo"]` syntax instead, remembering to create a pipeline:

```
 [.id, .slug, (.["**provider**"] | .["icons"] | .["color_code"]) ]
```